# function for converting time to number of seconds

Tags: php, mysql

On our site, we have a lot of swimming times that we would like to convert to seconds.  i.e. 1:23:33.03 or 58:22.43.  Is there a PHP function that can do this?  A MySQL function?

Answer (score 11):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec

```
mysql> SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('22:23:00');
    -> 80580
mysql> SELECT TIME_TO_SEC('00:39:38');
    -> 2378
```

Comment: @zerkms - what about fractions of seconds?

Comment: nothing. mysql hasn't fractions at it's time/datetime datatypes :-S

Comment: Actually, MySQL will allow you to specify microseconds in date/time literals passed to the various date/time functions, and as a return value from some of those functions. It just won't store them in any DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP columns.

Answer (score 8):

```
function time2seconds($time='00:00:00')
{
    list($hours, $mins, $secs) = explode(':', $time);
    return ($hours * 3600 ) + ($mins * 60 ) + $secs;
}
```

From [here](http://www.arkinex.com/php/snippets/47/convert-time-into-duration-seconds/).

MySQL also has [TIME_TO_SEC()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec)

Comment: I probably wouldn't name it like that, but it's the right idea.

Comment: @jasonbar: you stole my answer

Comment: actually i downvoted not for stealing. and i post my comment about "stealing" before i saw his "Why the downvote?". so my comment is not answer to that. and just after that i changed my vote to +1 to be polite ;-)

Answer (score 1):

so if mysql without fractions not appropriate solution - here is another mine

```
$time = '1:23:33.03';

$parts = explode(':', $time);

$seconds = 0;

foreach ($parts as $i => $val) {
    $seconds += $val * pow(60, 2 - $i);
}

echo $seconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following program for converting time to seconds in php.

```
<?php
function time_to_sec($time) {
    $hours = substr($time, 0, -6);
    $minutes = substr($time, -5, 2);
    $seconds = substr($time, -2);

    return $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
}

$result=time_to_sec('12:25:59');
echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

$current_time_in_seconds="01:21:44.24";

```
 list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(":", $current_time_in_seconds);

 $current_time_in_seconds=$hours*3600+$minutes*60+$seconds;
```

will get from

01:21:44.24

to

4904.24

Answer (score -1):

[Strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is what you need. You get a Unix timestamp which in this case would be the number of seconds.

Comment: Not so much looking for a time of day, looking for a conversion of a swimming time in HH:MM:SS.XX or MM:SS.XX to total seconds

Comment: Again, you could just use strtotime to convert between timelaps to total seconds.

Answer (score -1):

I am a little confused but I think that you mean. 1 hour, 23 minuts and 23.03 seconds.

this is not difficult to do. I made this PHP function that does that. My php server doesn't want to start up, so I couldn't test it, but I think it should work.

```
function ConvertTimeToSeconds($T)
{
    $exp = explode(":",$T);
    $c = count($exp);
    $r = 0;
    if ($c == 2)
    {
        $r = (((int)$exp[0]) * 60) + ((int)$exp[1]);
    }else{
        $r = (((int)$exp[0]) * 3600) + (((int)$exp[1]) * 60) + ((int)$exp[2]);
    } 

    return $r;
}

ConvertTimeToSeconds("1:23:33.03");
```